# Device IP is not visible for one particular client

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip

In my home network, I have 2 routers. Lets call them master and slave.

- Master is the one which is receiving internet connection from WAN.
- Slave is "bridged" through WIFI / BSSID. From this slave I have a LAN cable connection to my destination device (heat pump).

Usually I connect (with whatever else device) on the master. From "all" my devices (iPhone, Notebook) I can connect to the slave and even to the IP of the destination device.

Unfortunately, from the most important device (Desktop) which I would like to use as a server for running cronjobs like registering temperatures every 10 minutes, etc. I am not able to even ping that device as well as I am not able to connect on that device.

From this desktop I cannot even reach the slave router while from any other device I can.

On master I am running 5G and 2.4G on slave only 2.4G.

Can somebody help me how to find the problem?

If I connect straightly on slave from whatever device, I can reach the destination. But I cannot through the master router.

Comment: Are the routers on two different subnets?  Or is WIreless isolation enabled?

Comment: Please edit your question: This has nothing to do with 5G or 2.4G but it is ultimately a subnet issue. So please provide IP addresses related to the devices and perhaps provide some networking info for both devices.